# What exactly does iCloud integrate with

Tags: ios, icloud

From a developers standpoint, what is possible to integrate with iCloud.  I understand currently iCloud integrates with Contacts, Apps, etc. but is there a way to integrate other things, does anyone have a complete list they can offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can additionally store plists or files in iCloud for synchronization across multiple machines (Mac, iOS).  You need to join the developer program for the full details from Apple.

> http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php

According to Wikipedia, it acts as a "data syncing center for email, contacts, calendars, bookmarks, notes, to-do lists, and other data".

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICloud